# Switch { and [ in TexWorks

Tags: formatting

Does anyone know if it's possible in Texworks (or any editor for that matter) to switch the keyboard position of [ with { (and ] with } ) and vice versa of course. I never use square brackets and not pressing the shift key all the time to get accolades would be pretty nice I think.

I make new commands in Latex very often to save time by not writing out the entire command and would like to go a step further.

I do want to contain this to just my editor though, I use square brackets in other programs and don't want to change anything systemwide.

Best

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Even for latex code?

Comment: The position of brackets are country specific. If your OS is set to map the keys like your physical keyboard everything is fine. I would not change anything - the advantage is that you will get used to the keyboard, and be able to write in any program and on any computer(in your country).

Comment: I know that the set up is specific for my country. I'm using an international configuration and have bought one with latex in mind with the \ key above the enter key instead of left on the enter key such as in Europe. I would like to go further configuring my laptop for latex. I think it's a waste that I have to press the shift key and it does more harm than good, that's not too crazy to think right?

Comment: @user1792605 Which OS do you have? For example for mac there is a program (karabiner) that let's you modify the key behaviour of idividual keys

Comment: I guess there are system workarounds, but I'm not looking for that. In Mathematica I need to use the [ key very often. I'm on Windows btw.

Maybe it seems weird but I think it won't give me any problems in other programs if I'm not pressing the shift key in Latex.

Comment: you say you would be interested in any editor, emacs lets you bind any key to any list expression so it can do anything, defaulting to inserting iteself, but if you want `[` to insert `{` or run bibtex or do anything else that could be defined globally for all files in the editor or just in tex-mode for tex files. Do you really not use `[` in latex, never `\documentclass[a4paper]` or `\newcommand\foo[1]` ?

Comment: Since your on Windows I would seriously recommend you look at AutoHotKey per the answer by Jhore.  The key-swaps can easily be invoked with a call to your latex editor start-up and can be readily focused to that window only, thus can be left running whilst using other apps. Other system key mapping software is not usually easy to focus on a single app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a French user of TeXworks, I have a French "AZERTY" keyboard instead of the QUERTY one that you seem to use ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY)).

On this keyboard, `{` and `}` are obtained with `AltGr+4` and `AltGr+=`and for `[` and `]` it is `AltGr+5` and `AltGr+)` (note `AltGr` can sometimes by emulated by `Ctrl+Alt`).
All of them are terrible complication for coding, especially for LaTeX (and Mathematica too).
I have a TeXworks-LaTeX workaround that I find convenient : remap the needed keys to F9 and F10 keys using scripts, as for example :

```
// TeXworksScript
// Title: Insert }
// Shortcut: Shift+F10
// Description: Shortcut for }
// Author: *****
// Version: 0.1
// Date: 2012-11-23
// Script-Type: standalone
// Context: TeXDocument    
TW.target.insertText("}");
```

However,if you really want yo swap the effect of your `[/]` with that of `{/}`, without modifiers, it won't work.

An alternative, as you work on Windows, is  [`AutoHotkey`](https://autohotkey.com) which does the job with a script like :

```
:*?:[::{{ Down}
:*?:]::{} Down}
:*?:{::{[ Down}
:*?:}::{] Down}
```

and if you want to restrict your script to `Texworks` you would add in front of these 4 lines :

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive TeXworks
```

The drawback is that you will have to launch `AutoHotkey` when you load `Texworks`. This could be also triggered by a script in `Texworks`...

Note: of course, I have tested this code by setting my keyboard in EN/qwerty mode.